# Baking Adjustments When Using a Countertop Oven

Tags: baking, oven, temperature, cooking-time

I'm planning to bake some scones for a friend, but they only have a simple countertop oven. Although it's rated up to 250W, I would like to know if I should make any adjustments (I'm used to baking with a conventional, fan-assisted oven). Should I:

1. Change nothing
2. Keep the temperature unchanged and lengthen the cooking time (originally 15 minutes)
3. Keep the time the same and increase the temperature (originally 180°C)
4. Something else?

Sorry if this is obvious, but I just want to be prepared as I've never used this kind of oven before. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to change anything... 180 C is the same temperature regardless of the oven. The only reason you'd need to change anything is if the oven doesn't get to the proper temperature, so, if you have one, take an oven thermometer with you to make sure it's operating correctly.

As long as the oven still gets to the temperature required by the recipe, it should work pretty much the same.

Though you'll probably need to make them in smaller batches depending on the size of the oven. Over-filling the oven will be bad.

Remember that cooking time is just a guideline, check at 15 minutes and they *should* be done but if they need a little longer, that's ok.

Comment: Although a fan in a oven will not augment the temperature -it will  accelerate the heat transfer: 180 c is an average, but the same temp obtained in a broiler on low setting, in a very small oven with no preheating, in a big oven with preheat or in an oven with a fan will give totally different results.

Comment: @P.Obertelli I don't think the OP implied that it was a broiler oven or that she was planning to not preheat it. Did I miss that somewhere?

Comment: I was enumerating all the type of oven, which, even at the same temperature would give different results. As for OP, from my own experience, you can lower the temp by around 15c (keeping the same time ) for a good fan oven compared to a conventional one, or keep the same temperature but reduce the time by as much as 20%

Comment: @P.Obertelli If you have advice for the OP, then answer the question yourself. There's no need to refute it on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that smaller ovens do tend to crisp the top (or bottom) more quickly, as the heating element is closer to the food surface.

For scones, you may want to

- prepare it in smaller batches,
- lower the temperature by a few degrees, and crank it up for the last 3-5 minutes to get a more even bake and better cooked insides, while still getting a crispy crust.
- arrange each batch along the "spine" so that it is evenly spaced between the two elements on the top (strictly speaking, not necessary, but it compensates for any faulty fan action and allows the top to crisp more evenly)